# make Kile syntax highlight extension aware

Tags: kile, syntax-highlighting

Is is possible to make kile use a specific syntax highlight scheme for different kinds of files? I have a documentwith a .tex file as main file, but I also work with some sage script, and some sagetex inside te .tex document.

It would really be nice if the syntax highlight was adapted for each kind of file, and really awesome if inside some \begin{sagesilen} .. \end{sagesilent} environment the appropriate sage (or python) highlighting scheme was used.

Suggestions?